# Jquery animate container horizontally past page positioned relatively

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am fooling around with a website and I ran into a problem. As you can see below the problem is that when I click one of the boxes the box animates by vertically and horizontally expanding and the container expands vertically, but it doesn't manage to expand horizontally. The container is positioned relatively to the contents inside of it. I was wondering if there was an easy way to make it expand horizontally through its relative positioning without hard coding the expansion into the Jquery. Thanks (I can post code if necessary)

[image: Before Clicking]
[image: After Clicking]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question. It was simply to add:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the parent div's css. This allows overflow in the horizontal direction. Keep in mind the parent element is positioned **relative** to the child elements.